# reading na in columns with blank spaces -R

Tags: r

when I tried to read excel file which has blank space but it got replaced with

NA in blank space I am trying to replace it with while space or with any digit for all

[image]

As it is replaced with NA when I am trying join two columns it is reading as

[image]

but it is reading as (first 3 letter from both columns if any on column is empty it should skip it)

abcNA

i want it to be

abc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing your data is in a data frame called `df`, you can do

```
df[is.na(df)] = ""
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

df[is.na(df)] <- " "